# How to improve performance with numpy and pandas

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I have the following code with performance issues, it take about 1:30 minute to run with 1700 register in data list, I want to implement numpy or pandas dataframe concat, or both to get better performance but I don't know how to use it properly

```py
def json_to_excel(dtAltaInicial: date, dtAltaFinal: date):
    path = '../../public/exporta_dados.xlsx'
    start = timer()
    data = getAttendance(dataAltaInicial=str(dtAltaInicial),dataAltaFinal=str(dtAltaFinal))
    print(len(data))
    result = [flatten_data(item) for item in data]
    df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(result))
    df.to_excel(path, index=False, header=True)
    end = timer()
    print(timedelta(seconds=end-start))
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="exporta_dados.xlsx"'}
```

flatten_data function, used to remove nested objects:

```py
def flatten_data(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out
```

getAttendance function, used to get all attendaces from url and return a array with all responses:

```py
def getAttendance():
    url = 'https://api.com.br/search'
    headers = {...}
    body={...,page: 1}

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    total = data['total']
    data = data['items']
    totalPages = ceil(total / 100)

    if totalPages > 1:
        data = getAllPages(url, headers, totalPages, body, data)

    data = data if total > 0 else None
    return data
```

getAllPages function, if the response return more than one page, it goes through a loop to get all pages and append to the list:

```py
def getAllPages(url, headers, totalPages, body, data):
    atendimentos = []
    atendimentos = atendimentos + data
    for i in range(2, totalPages + 1):
        body.update({'page': i})
        reponse = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
        data = json.loads(reponse.text)
        atendimentos = atendimentos + data['items']

    return atendimentos
```

I accept any other advice.

I tried to append the response direct to pandas df but it overwrote the pages that I got before

Comment: Why do you feel the performance issue is with `pandas` or `numpy` and not with getting more than 1700 web results?

Comment: @JonSG I know the problem is the amount of results, but I think it should run faster if I implement numpy or make a better use of pandas

Comment: Numpy speed up computational operations on native-typed array. It cannot speed up web-based operation. It does not even have functions to do such a thing. As for Pandas, it is meant to do dataframe operations. Like JonSG said, it is likely that the web operation are slow and so Numpy/Pandas should not be an issue here. Using *asynchronous* requests should reduce the latency of the operations in the critical path and thus make the operation much faster (assuming it is latency bound which is certainly the case).

Comment: The first thing you need to do before optimizing something is to **profile your code first** (using a profiler if possible). It avoid you wasting efforts optimizing things that are not slow.